# merge multi-indexed column names on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that has its column names separated over various lines, like this:

```
ID,Flow,Flow
,,Type
1,21.79,1
2,1129.32,0
```

So the column names are `ID`, `Flow`, and `FLow Type`. When I read this csv as a multi-indexed dataframe:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(path, header = [0,1])
```

I end up with

```
               ID                Flow      
Unnamed: 0_level_1  Unnamed: 1_level_1  Type 
1                    21.79                1                             
2                    1129.32              0
```

Is there a simple way to merge the column names, so that I end up with a simple column index with their proper names? In the end, I would like to have the equivalent of

```
pandas.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2], 'Flow': [21.79, 1129.32], 'Flow Type': [1,0]})
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv('temp.csv', skiprows=2, names=['ID', 'Flow', 'FLow Type'])` may be? Assuming you know the header `names` , then you could `skiprows`.

Answer (score 0):

This method assumes you know the order to columns and their names, and number of rows you want to skip.

If so, you could

`pd.read_csv('temp.csv', skiprows=2, names=['ID', 'Flow', 'FLow Type'])`

Here, column names are `['ID', 'Flow', 'FLow Type']` and we are skipping `skiprows=2` from the 'temp.csv' file.

That shall read the csv in intended way. However, this method woudn't work if column order and skiprows changes.